# A 5x5 board has 25 cells.The numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are written on every row,every column and the two main diagonals.

Tags: puzzle, latin-square

A 5x5 board has $25$ cells. The numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are written on every row,every column and the two main diagonals without any repetition. If the sum of the numbers of the diagonal below the leading diagonal be represented as $A$. Show that $A\ne 20$. Also find the maximum possible value of $A$.

I could prove that $A\ne 20$ by showing that each of the cells of the diagonal below the leading diagonal cannot be $20$ as if such arrangement exists, then the board cannot have $5$ five times, which actually should be by the given condition of the question.

For the second part, I can imagine the maxiumum value to be $17$. For which I proved that $5$ can occur only $2$ times in the four cells and probably $4$ cannot occur twice. But I got no formal proof. Please help!

Comment: Gvien any construction, the sum of all numbers is 75 and the sum of numbers on the leading diagonal is 15. So the maximum value of $A$ is at least $(75-15)/2=30$. How do you get 17?

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get $A=30$?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. I assume that you mean to assign a value to each cell so that each row, each column, and each diagonal has {1,2,3,4,5}. So the sum of all numbers is 75. The leading diagonal has sum 15. So the upper sum + the lower sum = 60. One of them is at least 30. If it is the upper sum, just flip the matrix.

Comment: I was talking about the diagonal just below the leading diagonal.

Comment: Sorry I thought you mean all numbers below the diagonal.

Comment: I have edited the question to make out the meaning clearly. Please tell me if you still have any doubts regarding the meaning of the question.

Comment: There are 4 entries, so all must be 5 to achieve 20. That means the upper right entry must be a 5, so there is no 5 on the downward main diagonal.

Comment: How about using the greedy algorithm and checking at each step if it violates any given conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be at most $2$ equal numbers on subdiagonal:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&A&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\ \hline
\end{array}
\implies
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&A \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&A&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&A&.\\
\hline
.&.&A&.&. \\ \hline
\end{array};
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&A&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\ \hline
\end{array}
\implies
\varnothing;
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&A&. \\ \hline
\end{array}
\implies
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&A&.&.&. \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&A&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&A\\
\hline
.&.&.&A&. \\ \hline
\end{array};
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\
\hline
.&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&A&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&A&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\ \hline
\end{array}
\implies
\varnothing;
$$

(other cases are symmetrical).

Other $2$ cells cannot be filled with $2$ equal numbers, because we will get collision in red cell:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&. \\
\hline
A&.&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&A&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&B&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&.&B&. \\ \hline
\end{array}
\implies
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
.&.&.&.&\color{red}{A,B} \\
\hline
A&B&.&.&.\\
\hline
B&A&.&.&.\\
\hline
.&.&B&A&.\\
\hline
.&.&A&B&. \\ \hline
\end{array}.
$$

So, subdiagonal has either $4$ different numbers, or $2$ equal and $2$ different.

$4$ different numbers can reach only value of $14$: $5+4+3+2$.

$2$ equal and $2$ different numbers can reach value of $17$: $5+5+4+3$, and **no more**.

Examples:

$4\;3\;2\;1\;5 ~~~~~~~ 1\;5\;4\;3\;2$ 
$5\;2\;1\;4\;3 ~~~~~~~ 5\;3\;2\;4\;1$ 
$1\;5\;3\;2\;4 ~~~~~~~ 2\;4\;5\;1\;3$ 
$3\;1\;4\;5\;2 ~~~~~~~ 4\;1\;3\;2\;5$ 
$2\;4\;5\;3\;1 ~~~~~~~ 3\;2\;1\;5\;4$